# Apache .htaccess - DATA_PATH causes error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` with the following code:

```
SetEnv BASE_URL http://localhost:86/extranet/
SetEnv LOG_PATH C:\wamp\www\extranet\logs\
SetEnv SERVER_ROOT C:\wamp\www\
SetEnv SITE_ROOT C:\wamp\www\extranet\
SetEnv DATA_PATH C:\wamp\www\extranet\data\
```

The DATA_PATH causes this error in Apache

```
SetEnv takes 1-2 arguments, an environment variable name and optional value to pass to CGI., referer: http://localhost:86/
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please note, this is running in WAMP :)

Comment: Do you have any comments or stray spaces at the end of the `DATA_PATH` line?

Comment: Hi, no nothing like that, I retyped it on a new line in case of hidden characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be more complex than previously thought. First because it was on Windows I used `backslashes` but this was wrong. Also I had `<IfModule mod_#Rewrite.c>` in the file as well. This was causing some conflicts so I removed those tags. The `Rewrite` still works without those tags.